# Dynamics : Projectiles

Tags: dynamical-systems

If a cannon ball is fired at a target, where the line $L$ joining the point of projection to the target makes an angle $\alpha$ to the horizontal, and the target is at height $h$ above the point of projection.

Show that if the cannon ball is fired at an angle $\alpha+\beta$ to the horizontal and it hits the target in a direction perpendicular to the line $L$, then

$$\tan \alpha \tan \beta= \frac{1}{2}$$

Confused as how to tackle the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  x &= ut\cos \theta \\
  y &= ut\sin \theta-\frac{gt^2}{2} \\
  y &= x\tan \theta-\frac{gx^2}{2u^2\cos^2 \theta} \tag{1} \\
  \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} &= \frac{u\sin \theta-g t}{u\cos \theta} \\
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= \tan \theta-\frac{gx}{u^2\cos^2 \theta} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

$2\times (1)-x\times (2)$, $$  2y-x\frac{dy}{dx} = x\tan \theta \\$$

Now
\begin{align*}
  x &= h\cot \alpha \\
  y &= h \\
  \theta &= \alpha+\beta \\
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= -\cot \alpha \\
\end{align*}

Therefore
\begin{align*}
  2h-(h\cot \alpha)(-\cot \alpha) &= (h\cot \alpha)\tan (\alpha+\beta) \\
  2\tan \alpha+\cot \alpha &=
  \frac{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}{1-\tan \alpha \tan \beta} \\
  2\tan \alpha+\cot \alpha-2\tan^2 \alpha \tan \beta-\tan \beta
  &= \tan \alpha+\tan \beta \\
  \tan \alpha+\cot \alpha &= 2\tan \beta+2\tan^2 \alpha \tan \beta \\
  (1+\tan^2 \alpha)\cot \alpha &= 2(1+\tan^2 \alpha)\tan \beta \\
  \tan \alpha \tan \beta &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

hint...set up axes parallel to and perpendicular to the slope and write down the equations of motion. Use the condition that $\dot{x}=0$ when $y=0$